Help in changing the form of an equation (change the dependent and independent variables)
is there an online tool to convert the form of an equation to change the dependent and independent variables?
Here is my original equation:
$$R = (1 + Gy)^{xT}(1 - y)^{(1 - x)T}$$
I want to express $y$ as a function of $x, G, R, T$ where G, R and T are constants.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Short answer: no, There is no nice algebraic solution to your problem. (Even if there were finding software to do the work would be a challenge.)

Thanks @EthanBolker .. Can you help me understand why? Also, how does one approach a problem like this? What I am essentially trying to do is to understand the behavior of a system that involves 5 variables, but as a first step, I am pinning down 3 of them to be constant and doing a sensitivity analysis with the remaining 2.

More context - R is the money multiple that a trader would generate after T trades, x of which generate a profit that is G (Gain/Loss ratio) times the loss (y) generated per trade in the remaining (T-x) trades. I am trying to understand what level of loss per trade y can I sustain if I am correct x out of T times in picking the right trade.

The complex expression with variables both in sums in the factors and in the exponents rules out algebraic help. I suggest putting the expression in a spreadsheet, varying parameters and looking at plots of the results.

Yes, that is exactly what I am doing now... Thanks...

You're welcome. You should delete the question or put your spreadsheet results into an answer and accept it so that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.

I'd like to keep this open in case someone somewhere comes up with a systematic solution. Maybe will close 6 months down the line.
